# Visual Studio is Pulling Wrong CSS File on Debug

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I recently had to download a new version of my site from my team explorer. Now it seems to be having problems using the correct css file. It's as if it's looking at an older version somewhere, but I can't tell why or where it would be looking.

I've checked the bundle and it has the correct file name/location. I've checked the file and it has the correct code.

Here's my code

Layout (upto Head minus analytics)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Coverpools Dealer Portal</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/magnific_css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="~/Content/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

</head>
```

bundles (including all, in case I'm missing something)

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.Web
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/quotes").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                        "~/Scripts/quotes.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/magnific").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/site.css",  
                "~/Content/PagedList.css", 
                "~/Content/Responsive.css", 
                "~/Content/custom.css")); // this is the custom file I believe it should be pulling

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/magnific_css").Include("~/Content/magnific-popup.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));

        }
    }
}
```

custom.css from my local site (what it should be located in ..Web/Content/custom.css)

```
/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/


/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/


/* NOTICE THIS SECTION IS MISSING THE RUNNING VERSION menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#accountMenu {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
ul#accountMenu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
ul#accountMenu li a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#accountMenu li a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* page elements
----------------------------------------------------------*/
/*Text*/

.important-message{
    color: red
}


/* featured */


/* page titles */


/* features */


/* ordered list */



/* content */

/* login page */

/* contact */


/* forms */


/* info and errors */


/* styles for validation helpers */


/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/


/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
/*@media only screen and (max-width: 850x) { */

    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/


    /* logo */


    /* login */



    /* menu */


    /* main layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/


    /* page content */


    /* ordered list */


    /* features */


    /* forms */

    /* login page */



    /* mobile footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
```

custom.css (from the running version)

```
/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/


/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/


/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/



/* page elements
----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* featured */


/* page titles */


/* features */


/* ordered list */



/* content */

/* login page */

/* contact */


/* forms */


/* info and errors */


/* styles for validation helpers */


/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/


/********************
*   Mobile Styles   *
********************/
@media only screen and (max-width: 850x) {

    /* header
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/


    /* logo */


    /* login */



    /* menu */


    /* main layout
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/


    /* page content */


    /* ordered list */


    /* features */


    /* forms */

    /* login page */



    /* mobile footer
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Generated HTML upto Head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>All Users - Coverpools Dealer Portal</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <link href="/Content/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
```

I even tried hardcoding custom.css  but still get the same custom.css file. It's as if it's looking for the file somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like there is browser's caching issue different browser has different caching policies though your css is cached in browser so it's always get old one what i want you to do is just put **`?foo=1234`** at the end of your css / js import, changing 1234 to be whatever you like. Have a look at the SO html source for an example.

The idea there being that the ? parameters are discarded / ignored on the request anyway and you can change that number when you roll out a new version.

**OR**

Try to do **HARD REFRESH** by pressing `ctrl+R` | `ctrl+shift+R` | `cntrl+F5` or you can find how to refresh hard on this [link](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/2015/03/tech-tip-how-to-do-hard-refresh-in-browsers/) for different browser

Comment: Thank You, that was it. Now, I feel dumb. I could've sworn I'd cleared my cache and even tried a different browser that had never used this  css file. The weird part about this is I had run the later version of the solution with the correct css file many times before I had to redownload the solution. It's been several weeks since my css file didn't include these changes.